# The difference between "I never followed you" and "I've never followed you"

Tags: verbs, past-tense, present-perfect

If someone says to me that

> You unfollowed me!

Which answer is correct?

> 1) I never followed you
>
> 2) I've never followed you

I feel like both are correct, but I can't understand the difference between them.

Comment: Take a look at this question https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15535/i-have-never-said-versus-i-never-said

Answer (score -1):

​Ref: Cambridge E.D. [enter link description here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/have)
**strong text**
**I've**
UK ​  /aɪv/ US ​  /aɪv/

short form of I have:

**have**
auxiliary verb [ + past participle ] UK ​  strong /hæv/ weak /həv/ /əv/ US ​  strong /hæv/ weak /həv/ /əv/ had | had (also 've/'s)

**​used with the past participle of other verbs to form the present perfect and past perfect:**

Answer

1) I never followed you: has no indication of tense

2) I've never followed you: indicates the tense as described above Therefore I suppose technically 2 is correct. However Followed as opposed to Follow shows an indication of tense in the use of **ed** at the end

Ref as above:  **-ed suffix** [enter link description here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ed)

(also -d) UK ​  / -t/ /-d/ /-ɪd/ /-əd/ US ​  / -t/ /-d/ /-ɪd/ /-əd/
​
used to form the past simple and past participle of regular verbs: